# Unable to open a docker app running on a port

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image of https://filebrowser.xyz/installation

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt install curl -y

RUN curl -fsSL https://filebrowser.xyz/get.sh | bash

VOLUME /srv

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT filebrowser -r /srv -p 8080
```

I built the image and run it by `docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /home:/srv filemanager`

The logs say `Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080`. However when I open localhost:8080, it doesn't work, connection failed

I've confirmed that port 8080 is available by running a sample Nginx docker image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filebrowser is listening on the loopback address. Change it to listen on all addresses using `0.0.0.0`

Use `--address` option to run on the `*:8080`

Change the ENTRYPOINT to the following -

```
ENTRYPOINT filebrowser -r /srv -a 0.0.0.0 -p 8080
```

Logs will show something like

```
Listening on [::]:8080
```

Answer (score 2):

`Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080` means that the sever is literally listening on the loopback interface of the docker container. I.e. it will not be accessible outside of the container.

To make it work, you need to configure `filebrowser` to run on `*:8080`.

UPDATE

`docker run -p 8080:8080 -v ~/some/path/filebrowser.json:/.filebrowser.json -v ~/some-path:/srv filemanager`

works for me, where `filebrowser.json` contains

```
{
  "port": 8080,
  "baseURL": "",
  "address": "",
  "log": "stdout",
  "database": "/database.db",
  "root": "/srv"
}
```

Correct log prints

```
2019/08/12 17:14:27 Using config file: /.filebrowser.json
2019/08/12 17:14:27 Listening on [::]:8080
```